# WooCommerce Edit Account throwing 'display name is a required field' error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with WooCommerce edit account page. When submitting the form the error message 'display name is a required field' displays. I've attempted adding a field both

`input type="text"` and

```
<select name="display_name" id="display_name" >
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?></option>
</select>
```

but no luck trying to add the field. I've also attempted making the field not required but I'm unsure how to do they with the latest version of WooCommerce.

Comment: Investigating further I'm thinking this maybe an issue introduced when we switched the payment gateway over to Stripe? has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to make it not required, use this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'wc_save_account_details_required_fields' );
function wc_save_account_details_required_fields( $required_fields ){
    unset( $required_fields['account_display_name'] );
    return $required_fields;
}
```

If you wanted it required, to make the field for it, you need to give it a name attribute `'account_display_name'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use woocommerce shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]` on your page which has `current_user` in `args` array which is automatically set using `get_user_by( ‘id’, get_current_user_id() )` Reference: [woocommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

Try the following code. I think you should use `input` instead of `select`

```
<input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->display_name);?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
<select name="display_name" id="display_name" >
    <option selected="selected" value ="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, no luck unfortunately. I'm guessing that "display_name" is the correct value to send, I'm struggling to find any documentation for the edit account form.